# Getting highcharts to work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

so I've created a database to store scientific research data and i wanted to created graphs out of this data. i want to use Highcharts but i can't even get the example code form the Highcharts website to work. i am new to web development so i'm not really sure where i'm going wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script>

$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});


</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

<h2>Hey now brown cow</h2> 
</body>
</html>
```

also the "hey now brown cow" is just in there so i know the html file works.

Comment: what happens when you load the page? The code appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/4767wLwg/  Have you checked the console for javascript errors?

Comment: Thanks for checking. it does work. I believe my problem was that i wasn't clearing my cache on my browser and just opening new tabs.

Comment: So all wis fine, at this moemnt, right ?

Comment: Correct, i'm not sure of why it wasn't working before, but everything works now. Thanks!